# How to use material-ui and injectTapEventPlugin with gatsby

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

I got this error when I wrote AppBar tag from material-ui into a code generated by `gatsby new`.

```
Warning: Unknown prop `onTouchTap` on <button> tag. Remove this prop from the element.
```

To avoid this, I wrote these code at the top of root template (_template.jsx) file.

```
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
try {  // to prevent error because of loading twice
  injectTapEventPlugin();
}
catch(e) {
  console.warn( e );
}
```

This works perfectly with HMR, but it's ugly.
What is the correct way to resolve this problem?

UPDATE: To clarify - `gatsby new` clones [gatsby-starter-default](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default), and there are only React components.
Also, to import and write injectTapEventPlugin at the top of `/html.js` raises an error `Warning: Unknown prop onTouchTap on <button> tag`. It means injectTapEventPlugin() is not called properly.

Comment: You're importing injectTapEventPlugin in index.js right? Can you try putting it outside try?

Comment: I'm importing injectTapEventPlugin in pages/_template.js. If I put this without try, the following error will be appeared in HMR. `Error: injectTapEventPlugin(): Can only be called once per application lifecycle.`

Answer (score 0):

You could put that code in `html.js` and it'll work everywhere

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'

import { prefixLink } from 'gatsby-helpers'
import { TypographyStyle } from 'react-typography'
import typography from './utils/typography'
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

injectTapEventPlugin();

const BUILD_TIME = new Date().getTime()

export default class HTML extends React.Component {
...
```

You can take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/654) in gatsby repo on GitHub which also suggests that you put it in `html.js`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I started creating the pages by `gatsby new`. It clones this repository, and there is no `ReactDOM.render` in user code. https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default

Comment: @pall, I've edited my answer to better suit your problem. Could you try this again, run a build and check if the problem exist? If yes, could you tell us what is the problem then?

Comment: I got `Warning: Unknown prop `onTouchTap` on <button> tag.` and onTouchTap was not injected to an AppBar. It seems `injectTapEventPlugin();` was called only once before the `Server started successfully!` output when I restart `gatsby develop`. [info] I placed <MuiThemeProvider> in `pages/_template.jsx`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to import and add `injectTapEventPlugin` in your top level component from where you are rendering into your html element

```
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

injectTapEventPlugin();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'd like to know what file do you think as 'Top level component'? `html.js` is the top level component in the gatsby-starter-default, but it makes no effect when I putting injectTapEventPlugin at the top of this file.